# Multiple choice selection is not saving up in database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save the email and selection of multiple choise in mydatabase. With email everything is working properly, but there are some problems with selection('option'). It is not saving up in my database. This is my code:

views.py

```
if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            option = request.POST.getlist('my_field')
            new_user = form.save(email, option)
```

models.py

```
class Vartotojas(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    CHOICES = (
       ('s', 'small'),
       ('m', 'medium'),
       ('b', 'big'),
     )
    option = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CHOICES)
```

forms.py

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100)
my_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Vartotojas.CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def save(self, email, option):
        mymodel = Vartotojas(
        email=email,
        option = option,
        )
        mymodel.save()
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would avoid using _common_ names for fields, like `option`.

Comment: But is this a certain problem?

Comment: I'm not saying that is what's causing the issue your having, I'm saying that it _can_ lead to problems down the road.

Comment: Are you wanting them to be able to select more that one option?

Comment: "Are you wanting them to be able to select more that one option?" Yes, I do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't save a multiple choice field to a CharField. A CharField is a single element. A MulitpleChoiceField is, well, multiple. Plus you are setting the option field `max_length=1` so that won't work either.

What I suspect you want to do is to concatenate a series of choices to a single (comma-separated?) value in a CharField. You could do that with a standard `forms.TextField` (using a MultipleChoiceWidget) with a custom clean method that does the concatenation, but you'll need to remove the choices attribute from the destination CharField.

For example:

```
def clean_option_field(self):
    return ','.join(self.cleaned_data['option'])
```

Comment: As a note: this could cause problems if the input includes a comma.